# how to call methods with leading underscore and traling @ in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I have to call methods in dll but their names are like these _setParameterX@12 and  _getParameterX@20 using Java Native Access. How can I properly use FunctionMapper or StdCallFunctionMapper? How do I invoke these functions?  The jna documentation is a little vague to me.

Comment: It looks like C mangled function names in your Windows DLL. http://mearie.org/documents/mscmangle/. You can straight away use `setParameterX` and `getParameterX` in your JNA mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Those functions use the stdcall calling convention.  The suffix indicates the size of the incoming arguments on the stack.

You should use the `StdCallFunctionMapper` to automatically generate the appropriate mappings.  Create options similar to those used in the [W32API options](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/src/com/sun/jna/win32/W32APIOptions.java) (the function mapper there automatically chooses a -W or -A suffix for W32 API functions).  Pass your new options map to your invocation of [`Native.loadLibrary`](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.util.Map%29).

In addition, make sure you implement the `StdCallLibrary` interface so that the appropriate calling convention is used when calling the functions.

Comment: ok thanks for the information.... i'm having trouble accessing stackoverflow.com on my pc so I was not able to read my inbox....