# Error looking up function in a Borland DLL through JNA

Tags: java, dll, jna

Here is a running example of my `DLLService` :

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class DLLService {

public DLLService() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("version = " + version()  + "\n");
    testEvaluate();
}

public void testEvaluate() {
    System.out.println(this.loadFile("file", 1));
    int[] barre = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] result = new int[]{};
    evaluateParty(barre.length, barre, result, 1);
    System.out.println(result);
}

public int version() {
    return GDLL.INSTANCE.LireNoVersion();
}

public int loadFile(String tslName, int pdwNoSess) {
    return GDLL.INSTANCE.ChargerFichier();
}



public interface GDLL extends StdCallLibrary  {
    GDLL INSTANCE = (GDLL) Native.loadLibrary("tsr32_mini", GDLL.class);

    int LireNoVersion();
    int ChargerFichier();
}
}
```

There is no problem with the function `version()` but not with the `loadFile(...)`, I have the exception :

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'EvaluerPartie':
>
> at com.sun.jna.Function.(Function.java:212)   at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:541)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:518)     at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:504)     at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:220)  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.EvaluerPartie(Unknown Source)   at
>   DLLService.evaluateParty(DLLService.java:29)  at
>   DLLService.testEvaluate(DLLService.java:16)   at
>   DLLService.(DLLService.java:9)  at
>   ProblemsIsolator.main(ProblemsIsolator.java:53)

I already search but found nothing that work (changing types, arguments, names, ...). Here is the prototype of the function l: `DWORD ChargerFichier (LPSTR chNom, DWORD *pdwNoSess)`.

**EDIT :**
Same error, even after using a name mapper; it works for the `LireVersion` only :

```
public void testFunctionMapper() throws Exception {
        FunctionMapper mapper = StdCallLibrary.FUNCTION_MAPPER;
        NativeLibrary lib = NativeLibrary.getInstance("tsr32_mini");

        Method[] methods = {
                GDLL.class.getMethod("LireNoVersion",
                                        new Class[] { String.class, int.class }),
                GDLL.class.getMethod("ChargerFichier",
                                        new Class[] { String.class, int.class }),
        };

        for (int i=0;i < methods.length;i++) {
            String name = mapper.getFunctionName(lib, methods[i]);
            lib.getFunction(name, StdCallLibrary.STDCALL_CONVENTION).getName();
        }
}
```

Also, a dependency worker showed me well of the methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call methods with leading underscore and traling @ in JNA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578457/how-to-call-methods-with-leading-underscore-and-traling-in-jna)

Comment: i've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems to works in that link: [How do I get a java JNA call to a DLL to get data returned in parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17380916/how-do-i-get-a-java-jna-call-to-a-dll-to-get-data-returned-in-parameters), I can see that your definition of `ChargerFichier` is missing parameters.

Maybe the definition should be something like:

```
int ChargerFichier(PointerByReference chNom, IntByReference pdwNoSess);
```

Maybe this link can help you too: http://www.viaboxx.de/code/java-interoperation-with-a-native-dll-using-jna/

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'd use the `StdCallFunctionMapper`:

```
Map options = new HashMap();
options.put(Library.OPTION_FUNCTION_MAPPER, new StdCallFunctionMapper());
MyLib lib = (MyLib)Native.loadLibrary("tsr32_mini", MyLib.class, options);
```

Comment: Thank you for proposing but I tried and still the same error message

Comment: Is there any other reason why it does not work for all the methods that have arguments ?

Comment: Can you please include the depends.exe dump and/or DLL symbols for the relevant method?